# Using Meteor to do $push and $set at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to use Meteor to do both a `$push` and a `$set` in the same operation?

I want it to be in the same operation so a `cursor.observe` will not be triggered twice by splitting up into 2 different MongoDB operations.

Currently, the following fails to insert into the array:

```
Animals.update(
    {_id: animal_id}, 
    { 
        $set: {
            driver_id: '', 
            status: 'feeding'
        }, 
        $push: {
            feeder: Meteor.user()._id 
        }
    }   
)
```

For `$push` to work, it needs to be split into 2:

```
Animals.update(
    {_id: animal_id}, 
    { $set: 
        {
            driver_id: '', 
            status: 'feeding'
        }
    }
Animals.update(
    {_id: animal_id}, 
    {
        $push: {
            feeder: Meteor.user()._id 
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you see any error when insert fails ? It works fine for me from mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both into a `$set` by extracting the array first, pushing onto it, then including it.

```
const animal = Animals.findOne(animal_id);
let feeder = [] && animal.feeder;
feeder.push(Meteor.userId);

Animals.update(animal_id, 
    { 
        $set: {
            driver_id: '', 
            status: 'feeding'
            feeder: feeder
        }
    }   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple updates may be performed on the same document, as long as those updates do not conflict (hence the "have conflicting mods in update" error).

Because `"$push" : {"bugs" : [{"name":"bug1", "count":1}]}` and `"$inc" : {"bugs.0.count" : 1}` are both attempting to modify the same portion of the document (namely the "bugs" array), they conflict.

Multiple updates may be combined if each affects a different part of the document:

Comment: His set/push doesn't have key conflicts yet isn't working.